# apns push notification not sent : Baddevicetoken

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

I have a problem with apns sharp:

I get the device token from my iTunes for the iPhone, and I put it into the program.

However I am getting a `baddevicetokenexception : 40 , invalid ...` error.
He must have 64 characters.

I don't know how to get a device token with 64 characters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your id is the unique identifier of the iPhone, but the devicetoken is the id to send to Apple for notifications.

To get the deviceToken :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
```